# glMaterialfv within a specific area

Tags: opengl, area, light

I use opengl in order to create a fire (with particles).
With this fire, I wanna create kind of "light effect".

I used the function  `glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION, emission);`
It's sound good but the problem is this function light all the scene.

I wanna just an emission with a specific area. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Setting a material will use it for all the objects on the scene.  If you only want to use it for a specific area, use the command you used to set the material how you want:

```
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION, emission);
```

Then draw your objects to use this material.
After you have drawn the objects, change the emission back to the default (if you read the man pages, or think about, this is (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0):

```
GLfloat r_emission[4] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION, r_emission);
```